# how to send an ID from an array that is inside a *ngFor to another component in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an array of items that I cycle using `ngFor`. I'm trying to send all its attributes to another component.

I tried using this code:

```
*ngFor='let item of listaPostagens
[routerLink]="['/post-detalhado', item.id]
```

And in the other component:

```
this.idPost = this.route.snapshot.params['id']
```

But I don't know what to do next. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do with the "this.idPost" field?

Answer (score 2):

If want you to open a new component's view on the router link click, with data that is associated with the "id" parameter, try doing the following steps

1. Register route in the "app-routing.module.ts" file.

   ```
   path : 'post-detalhado/:id', component:YourHandlerComponent
   ```
2. Inside the handler component, create a member method that will responsible for processing the "id" parameter.

   ```
   getHero(): void
   {
       const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
       // use this id local variable for further processing you want to do.
       // may be you want to show data associated with id 
   }
   ```
3. call member method inside ngOnInit event handler.

   ```
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getHero();
   }
   ```